# ILMerge even with XMLDocs switch, yields a dll that bears no intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, ilmerge

Has anyone experienced this or found a solution? I have tried the following:

1. Referencing the output dll directly without moving it
2. Uninstalling the output dll from the GAC

Neither option made a difference. Please note that the generated XML doc has the same name as the dll and is included with it.

Answer (score 2):

Ah ha. I found the reason why this was occurring.

If you referencing your *ILMerge* project within Visual Studio (i.e. as `Add Reference -> Project`) then *Intellisense* will not use the generated XML doc.

To solve: In your post-build step copy your output files to a common directory (e.g. `Reference Assemblies`) and then link against the DLLs. You can still have the project in the solution, however you must setup the project dependencies so that it will build if you have made changes.

HTH,

Comment: Wow thanks for this. This is an old answer, but still works in VS 2019!!